# Booting to grub from rEFInd

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

So I currently have arch linux(64 bit), Lubuntu(32 bit), and Windows 8(64bit) all installed on my Laptop(Thinkpad  t430). I instaled arch before lubuntu and was using rEFInd to boot into it and windows and all was well. After I installed lubuntu I had to change a setting in my bios to do a legacy boot rather than EFI boot. I had to do this because rEFInd was not seeing my lubuntu installion. However, when doing the legacy boot I get grub and can boot into lubuntu, but the windows entry in grub fails to boot.

My question is, can I tell rEFInd to have an entry for grub, which I can then use to boot lubuntu?

I've tried reading the rEFInd docs but I'm just getting very confused.

Answer (score 0):

I believe EFI is only supported with the 64 bit install.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

They emphasize 64 bit